# How to draw polygon when last point clicked?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to complete polygon when starting point of polygon clicked, i think i need to hide or set opacity of last line which is linking to first point of line.
goal is to achieve exactly what is happening in this GIF.
also i want to show angles and length on each line while drawing just like exactly same as GIF.

[image: goal to achieve]

```js
var bw = window.innerWidth -20;
    var bh = window.innerHeight -20;
    var p = 10;
    var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
    var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function drawBoard(){
        for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += 30) {
            context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
            context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
        }

        for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += 30) {
            context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
            context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
        }
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 122, 204,0.7)';
        context.stroke();
    }

    drawBoard();

//---------------------------------------------

requestAnimationFrame(update)

mouse = {x : 0, y : 0, button : 0, lx : 0, ly : 0, update : true};
function mouseEvents(e){
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  mouse.update = true;
}
["mousedown","mouseup","mousemove"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener(name,mouseEvents));

context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = "red";
const point = (x,y) => ({x,y});
const poly = () => ({
    points : [],
    addPoint(p){ this.points.push(point(p.x,p.y)) },
    draw() {
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "red";
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        context.beginPath();
        for (const p of this.points) { context.lineTo(p.x,p.y) }
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
        

        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
        for (const p of this.points) {

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(p.x + 10,p.y);
            context.arc(p.x,p.y,10,0,Math.PI *2);
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();
        }
        
        
    },
    closest(pos, dist = 8) {
        var i = 0, index = -1;
        dist *= dist;
        for (const p of this.points) {
            var x = pos.x - p.x;
            var y = pos.y - p.y;
            var d2 =  x * x + y * y;
            if (d2 < dist) {
                dist = d2;
                index = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (index > -1) { return this.points[index] }
    }
});
function drawCircle(pos,color="black",size=8){
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(pos.x,pos.y,size,0,Math.PI *2);
    context.stroke();
}
const polygon = poly();
var activePoint,cursor;
var dragging= false;
function update(){
    if (mouse.update) {
        cursor = "crosshair";
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        drawBoard();
        if (!dragging) {  activePoint = polygon.closest(mouse) }
        if (activePoint === undefined && mouse.button) {
            polygon.addPoint(mouse);
            mouse.button = false;
        } else if(activePoint) {
            if (mouse.button) {
                if(dragging) {
                    activePoint.x += mouse.x - mouse.lx;
                    activePoint.y += mouse.y - mouse.ly;
                } else {  dragging = true }
            } else { dragging = false }
        }
        polygon.draw();
        if (activePoint) { 
            drawCircle(activePoint);
            cursor = "move";
        }

        mouse.lx = mouse.x;
        mouse.ly = mouse.y;
        canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
        mouse.update = false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style=" background: lightblue;">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Drawing part of code i copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437943/3877726

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ctx.setTransform` to to align text to a line.

First normalize the vector between the end points and use that normalized vector to build the transform. See example.

To prevent text from reading back to front you need to check the x component of the normalized vector. If it is < 0 then reverse the vector.

Almost the same for the angle. See example.

### Example

Snippets contain the functions `drawLineText` and `drawAngleText` (near top) that implement the additional features.

```js
var bw = innerWidth - 20, bh = innerHeight - 20;
var cw = bw + (p * 2) + 1, ch = bh + (p * 2) + 1;
var p = 10;

var activePoint, cursor, dragging = false;
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, button: 0, lx: 0, ly: 0, update: true};

const TEXT_OFFSET = 5;
const TEXT_COLOR = "#000";
const TEXT_SIZE = 16;
const FONT = "arial";
const TEXT_ANGLE_OFFSET = 25;
const DEG = "°";

canvas.width = bw;
canvas.height = bh;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawLineText(p1, p2, text, textOffset = TEXT_OFFSET, textColor = TEXT_COLOR, textSize = TEXT_SIZE, font = FONT) {
    var x = p1.x, y = p1.y;
    var nx = p2.x - x, ny = p2.y - y, len = (nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
    nx /= len;
    ny /= len;
    ctx.font = textSize + "px " + font;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor;    
    if (nx < 0) { 
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        x = p2.x;
        y = p2.y;
        nx = -nx;
        ny = -ny;
        textOffset = -textOffset;
    } else { ctx.textBaseline = "bottom" }
    len /= 2;
    ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, x, y);
    ctx.fillText(text, len, -textOffset);        
}

// angle between p2-p1 and p2-p3
function drawAngleText(p1, p2, p3, textAngleOffset = TEXT_ANGLE_OFFSET, textColor = TEXT_COLOR, textSize = TEXT_SIZE, font = FONT) {
    var ang;
    var x = p2.x, y = p2.y;
    var nx1 = p1.x - x, ny1 = p1.y - y, len1 = (nx1 * nx1 + ny1 * ny1) ** 0.5;
    var nx2 = p3.x - x, ny2 = p3.y - y, len2 = (nx2 * nx2 + ny2 * ny2) ** 0.5;
    nx1 /= len1;
    ny1 /= len1;
    nx2 /= len2;
    ny2 /= len2;
    const cross = nx1 * ny2 - ny1 * nx2;
    const dot = nx1 * nx2 + ny1 * ny2;
    if (dot < 0) {
        ang = cross < 0 ? -Math.PI - Math.asin(cross) : Math.PI - Math.asin(cross);
    } else {
        ang = Math.asin(cross);
    }
    const angDeg = Math.abs(ang * (180 / Math.PI)).toFixed(0) + DEG;
    ctx.font = textSize + "px " + font;
    ctx.fillStyle = textColor;    
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    const centerAngle = Math.atan2(ny1, nx1) + ang / 2;
    const nx = Math.cos(centerAngle);
    const ny = Math.sin(centerAngle);
    if (nx < 0) {
        ctx.textAlign = "right";
        ctx.setTransform(-nx, -ny, ny, -nx, x, y);    
        textAngleOffset = -textAngleOffset;
    } else {
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, x, y);    
    }
    ctx.fillText(angDeg, textAngleOffset, 0);        
}


//---------------------------------------------
requestAnimationFrame(update)
function mouseEvents(e) {
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    mouse.update = true;
}
["mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener(name, mouseEvents));

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
const point = (x, y) => ({x, y});
const poly = () => ({
    points: [],
    closed: false,
    addPoint(p) { this.points.push(point(p.x, p.y)) },
    draw() {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (const p of this.points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y) }
        this.closed && ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        this.closed && ctx.fill();

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
        for (const p of this.points) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x + 10, p.y);
            ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }     
        this.points.length > 1 && this.drawLengthText();
        this.points.length > 2 && this.drawAngleText();
    },
    drawLengthText() {
        const len = this.points.length;
        var p1, i = 0;
        p1 = this.points[i];
        while (i < len -(this.closed ? 0 : 1)) {
            const p2 = this.points[((i++) + 1) % len];
            const lineLength = ((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
            drawLineText(p1, p2, lineLength.toFixed(0) + "px");
            if (len < 3) { break }
            p1 = p2;            
        }
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);        
    },
    drawAngleText() {        
        const len = this.points.length;
        var p1, p2, i = this.closed ? 0 : 1;
        p1 = this.points[(i + len - 1) % len];
        p2 = this.points[i];
        while (i < len -(this.closed ? 0 : 1)) {
            const p3 = this.points[((i++) + 1) % len];
            drawAngleText(p1, p2, p3);
            p1 = p2;            
            p2 = p3;
        }
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);                
    },
    closest(pos, dist = 8) {
        var i = 0,
        index = -1;
        dist *= dist;
        for (const p of this.points) {
            var x = pos.x - p.x;
            var y = pos.y - p.y;
            var d2 = x * x + y * y;
            if (d2 < dist) {
                dist = d2;
                index = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (index > -1) { return this.points[index] }
    }
});
const polygon = poly();
function drawCircle(pos, color = "black", size = 8) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function update() {
    if (mouse.update) {
        cursor = "crosshair";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (!dragging) { activePoint = polygon.closest(mouse) }
        if (activePoint === undefined && mouse.button) {
            polygon.addPoint(mouse);
            mouse.button = false;
        } else if (activePoint) {
            if (mouse.button) {
                if (dragging) {
                    activePoint.x += mouse.x - mouse.lx;
                    activePoint.y += mouse.y - mouse.ly;
                } else { 
                    if (!polygon.closed && polygon.points.length > 2 && activePoint === polygon.points[0]) {
                        polygon.closed = true;
                    }
                    dragging = true 
                }
            } else { dragging = false }
        }
        polygon.draw();
        if (activePoint) {
            drawCircle(activePoint);
            cursor = "move";
        }
        mouse.lx = mouse.x;
        mouse.ly = mouse.y;
        canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
        mouse.update = false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
```

```html
Click to add points
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;"></canvas>
```

<sup>**Note** though not mandatory it is customarily considered polite to include attributions when copying [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437943/3877726).</sup>

Comment: Thanks alot for great effort, i wasn't expecting even this is possible to do. i am new to canvas actually.
I have 2 more question on thing i noticed that you even not load canvas how is this code working then?
`var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");`
2nd question is what will the best practice to load grid as its mentioned in my question because whenever i use `clearRect` this will clear grid, because i may have several different drawing methods and i don't want to call grid function everywhere in my application after doing clearRect?