# How to draw parallelogram with draggable points

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been studying JS for a few days, but I need to draw a parallelogram and allow user to change its angles by dragging one of its points. I took a code from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427699/editing-selections-of-path-points-or-line), and tried to change it (I know, it's a nightmare). But the 4th point doesn't work properly. I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAjE6.png

How can I make the 4th point create a parallelogram?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var mouse = {};
var draggable = false;

context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = "blue";

var coordinates = [];
var isDone = false;
var clicks = 0;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  handleMouseDown(e);
});

function GetMassCenterAndFourthPoint(knownpoints) {
  let point4X = knownpoints[2].x - knownpoints[1].x + knownpoints[0].x;
  let point4Y = knownpoints[2].y - knownpoints[1].y + knownpoints[0].y;
  coordinates.push({
    x: point4X,
    y: point4Y
  });
}

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  mouse = oMousePos(canvas, e);
  //if isDone you can drag
  if (isDone) {
    for (index = 0; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
      // you draw a small circle no stroke, no fill
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(
        coordinates[index].x,
        coordinates[index].y,
        5,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      // if the mouse is inside the circle
      if (context.isPointInPath(mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
        // you can drag this point
        // I'm using index + 1 because index == 0 is false
        draggable = index + 1;
        // if I have a point a can break the loop 
        break;

      }
    }

  } else {
    coordinates.push({
      x: mouse.x,
      y: mouse.y
    });
    drawPolygon();
    clicks++;
    if (clicks === 3) {
      isDone = true;
    }
  }
}

function drawPolygon() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  if (isDone) {
    GetMassCenterAndFourthPoint(coordinates);
  }
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for (index = 1; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
    context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);


  }

  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
  // Additionaly I'm drawing a small circle around every point
  // you can delete this.
  for (index = 0; index < coordinates.length; index++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (isDone) {
    if (draggable) {
      mouse = oMousePos(canvas, e);
      // draggable - 1 is the index of the point in the coordinates array
      coordinates[draggable - 1].x = mouse.x;
      coordinates[draggable - 1].y = mouse.y;
      drawPolygon();
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  if (draggable) {
    draggable = false;
  }
});


// a function to detect the mouse position

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

I also tried to draw my own parallelogram, but can't do it draggable

```js
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
    startX;
    startY;
  }
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var mouse = {};
var draggable = false;





var points = [];
let isDone = false;
var clicks =0;
let click = false;

canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
    console.log(clicks);
    clicks++;
    if(!isDone){
        const point = new Point(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        points.push(point);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(point.x, point.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fill();
        if(clicks===3){
            isDone=true;
        }
        
       

    }
    if(isDone){
        
        GetMassCenterAndFourthPoint(points);
        drawParallelogramAndCircle(); 
    }
    
  
});



function GetMassCenterAndFourthPoint(knownpoints){
    const point4X = knownpoints[2].x-knownpoints[1].x+knownpoints[0].x;
    const point4Y = knownpoints[2].y-knownpoints[1].y+knownpoints[0].y;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(point4X, point4Y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fill();
    points.push(new Point(point4X, point4Y));

    const massCenterX = (knownpoints[1].x+knownpoints[3].x)/2;
    const massCenterY = (knownpoints[1].y+knownpoints[3].y)/2;
    
    
    points.push(new Point(massCenterX, massCenterY));

}

function drawParallelogramAndCircle(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    for(let i=1;i<points.length-1;i++){
        
        context.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        if(i===3){
            context.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        }
        
    }
    context.strokeStyle = "blue";
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
// find square. Here will be the logic to calculate square
    
    let square = 250;

    context.beginPath();
    
    context.arc(points[4].x, points[4].y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427699/editing-selections-of-path-points-or-line   from here, the first answer.